# Turn equation into code

Tags: java, loops, combinatorics

[The number of zero digits in the range [m,n]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CBIb.png)

Okay so i am trying to turn this formula(in the picture provided with link) into java code, i have something started but i am not sure that i did it correctly. Does anyone see something wrong with it?(variables are longs because i will be plugging in very large numbers into the equation)

```
long loop1 = 0, loop2 = 0;
    // put in a loop

    for (int k = 1; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.log10(k); i++) {
            loop1 += (1 - ((((k / Math.pow(10, i)) - (10 * (k / Math.pow(10, i + 1))))) / 10));
        }

    }
    for (int k = 1; k < m - 1; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.log10(k); i++) {
            loop2 += (1 - ((((k / Math.pow(10, i)) - (10 * (k / Math.pow(10, i + 1))))) / 10));
        }

    }

    answer = loop1 - loop2;
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem, or are you asking for a [codereview.se]?

Comment: This looks OK to me, at least from a quick glance.  If you have some known inputs and outputs, you could try testing against that.

Comment: I am simply looking for a code review sorry if it came off weird. i do have a few know inputs. for example m = 100 n = 200.  which should output 22 instead i get 301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues.  Here are some.

```
for (int k = 1; k < n; k++) {   // SHOULD BE k <= n.
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.log10(k); i++) {  // AGAIN USE <=
        // USE CEILING AND FLOOR FUNCTIONS NOT POWER. USE DOUBLE PRECISION NOT INTEGER.
        loop1 += (1 - ((((k / Math.pow(10, i)) - (10 * (k / Math.pow(10, i + 1))))) / 10));
    }

}
```

Seems like an interesting problem to solve.  Here is what i meant by using mod and division operators.  But this slows down linearly as n increases.  Perhaps another approach to tryout is to use memoization.  I will try another approach and post back.

```
public class ZeroCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        long end = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
        System.out.println("Number of zeros encountered from [" + start + "] to [" + end + "] : " +getZeroCount(start, end));

    }

    public static long getZeroCount(long begin, long end) {
        long zeroCount = 0;
        for (long curNum = begin; curNum <= end; curNum++) {
            if (curNum == 0) {
                zeroCount++;
                continue;   
            }       
            long tempNum = curNum;
            while (tempNum / 10.0 > 0) {
                if (tempNum % 10 == 0) {
                    zeroCount++;    
                }           
                tempNum /= 10;
            }       
        }   
        return zeroCount;

    }
}
```

Result:

```
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 100
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [100] : 12

real    0m0.066s
user    0m0.049s
sys     0m0.014s
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 1000
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [1000] : 193

real    0m0.070s
user    0m0.051s
sys     0m0.015s
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 10000
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [10000] : 2894

real    0m0.091s
user    0m0.061s
sys     0m0.015s
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 100000
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [100000] : 38895

real    0m0.076s
user    0m0.059s
sys     0m0.015s
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 1000000
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [1000000] : 488896

real    0m0.130s
user    0m0.114s
sys     0m0.015s
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 10000000
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [10000000] : 5888897

real    0m0.606s
user    0m0.592s
sys     0m0.015s
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 100000000
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [100000000] : 68888898

real    0m6.756s
user    0m6.728s
sys     0m0.024s
jeetatl$ time java ZeroCount 0 1000000000
Number of zeros encountered from [0] to [1000000000] : 788888899

real    1m8.226s
user    1m8.191s
sys     0m0.041s
```

Comment: Why would i use ceiling and floor instead of power?

Comment: Look at the notation for floor and ceiling at this link.  I see the same mathematics symbols in the image you posted.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation

Comment: Great! Glad to help!

Comment: Well i have an update. i put in the numbers 1234567890 and  2345678901 the program has been running for 10 minutes and still no output.. i honestly dont know what to use. is there a faster formula than the one i used?

Comment: The max value an integer can hold is 2147483647, if you add one to it, it will become a negative number.  Which means that your loop will never exit since k will never be bigger than n.  Try using 2147483646 as your upper limit and see if the program stops.

Comment: yeah the program still having issues i decided to lower m to 0 and n to 1000000 which makes the program finish in exactly .9875 seconds anything higher leads to the program taking minutes to finish

Comment: Alternatively, you can use long's in your for loops instead of ints.

Comment: if you like i can send you my source code to play with it. i tried to switch to longs but same problem exists,

Comment: How about using combination of % (mod) operator and division to count the number of zeros?

Comment: Loop from your start number to end number. For each number, do a mod 10 (num % 10) and see if it is 0, if it is, increment the counter. Then divide the current number by 10 and repeat the process until no more digits remain, move on to the next num and apply same process.

Comment: Memoization is like recursion?

Comment: Its retrieving the result if its already calculated, if not calculate it and store it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization